# Linux VM Serial Console Output "INFO ExtHandler Updated NIC state" every 3 minutes

Tags: linux, azure, cloud, virtual-machine

I have deployed a Linux VM on MS Azure, I connect to the same via serial console.

After I have installed Docker I get this output below every 2 minutes or so.

It is really annoying.

Is it normal when you use serial console?

I can see the docker interface with mtu 1500.

I'm not saying it is a network issue (remember it is a Azure VM).

```
          IP LINK STATUS BELOW
```

1: **lo:** <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00

2: **eth0**: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
link/ether 00:0d:3a:3a:00:f2 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff

3: **docker0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default**
link/ether 02:42:e4:b1:37:14 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff

**Any advise?**, cheers.

```
                OUTPUT DISPLAYED
```

```
21.397762 **INFO ExtHandler Updated NIC state:** [{ "name": "lo", "link": "<LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000\    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00 promiscuity 0 addrgenmode eui64 numtxqueues 1 numrxqueues 1 gso_max_size 65536 gso_max_segs 65535 " }, { "name": "docker0", "link": "**<NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN mode DEFAULT** group default \    link/ether 02:42:45:34:a2:90 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff promiscuity 0 \    bridge forward_delay 1500 hello_time 200 max_age 2000 ageing_time 30000 stp_state 0 priority 32768 vlan_filtering 0 vlan_protocol 802.1Q bridge_id 8000.2:42:45:34:a2:90 designated_root 8000.2:42:45:34:a2:90 root_port 0 root_path_cost 0 topology_change 0 topology_change_detected 0 hello_timer    0.00 tcn_timer    0.00 topology_change_timer    0.00 gc_timer  251.65 vlan_default_pvid 1 vlan_stats_enabled 0 group_fwd_mask 0 group_address 01:80:c2:00:00:00 mcast_snooping 1 mcast_router 1 mcast_query_use_ifaddr 0 mcast_querier 0 mcast_hash_elasticity 4 mcast_hash_max 512 mcast_last_member_count 2 mcast_startup_query_count 2 mcast_last_member_interval 100 mcast_membership_interval 26000 mcast_querier_interval 25500 mcast_query_interval 12500 mcast_query_response_interval 1000 mcast_startup_query_interval 3125 mcast_stats_enabled 0 mcast_igmp_version 2 mcast_mld_version 1 nf_call_iptables 0 nf_call_ip6tables 0 nf_call_arptables 0 addrgenmode eui64 numtxqueues 1 numrxqueues 1 gso_max_size 65536 gso_max_segs 65535 " }, { "name": "eth0", "link": " **<BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen1000\**     link/ether 00:0d:3a:46:0e:bc brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff promiscuity 0 addrgenmode eui64 numtxqueues 64 numrxqueues 64 gso_max_size 62780 gso_max_segs 65535 " }]
```

Comment: Your question is quite ambigious. I can't even understand whether your problem is network- or programming related. I suggest visiting [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to get a better insight on how to ask a solid question. Additionally, some code, errors, and a slightly better explanation is necessary for others to offer you help (they 1st need to understand what the actual issue is). Please edit your post accordingly. Good luck

Answer (score 1):

I had this Issue as well. I installed the latest docker version using this guide
https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/#install-using-the-repository
on a Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS. After the installation, the docker instance worked fine. However, I kept getting this message. After a reboot it just stops. I found the answer here: https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/2047631-azure-linux-vm-in-failed-state

**EDIT**
The mentioned issues seems to be occurring only on a the v18 VM. I installed docker on a 16.04.5 LTS.

Comment: In case the link goes away, the solution was the time-tested "turn it off and on again"